# Pin app programmatically

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

as I understood, from android 5.0 there's a option to pin apps in order to disable the process from being killed by the OS. 
is there a way to activate it on my app programmatically?

Comment: Fortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, but:

This is not a way to prevent OS from killing your app process. If you need that, foreground services are the way to go. Pinning app will lock user into your app and user will not be able to leave the app unless they press and hold back and overview buttons together (triangle and square buttons).

That being said, the method you need to call to pin your app is `startLockTask()`. It's an instance method on the `Activity` class. It's added to the API in Lollipop (API 21) so if your app supports earlier version you need to take that into account.

Comment: Note that going by [Set up Single-Purpose Devices](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) you need the device to be configured for COSU (corporate owned; single-use) and to be running a DPC (device policy controller). You can't (thankfully, if I'm reading that page right) just "take over" the device without the owner's explicit permission.

Comment: I think you're confusing app pinning with lock task mode. Not that anyone can blame you since you programmatically enter pin mode by calling a startLockTask() method. Take another look at the link you posted, at the very beginning it explains the difference between pinning the app and setting lock task mode. When app is pinned user can only navigate inside the app but if he taps and holds back and overview button app exits the pinned mode, so you don't really "take over" the device...

Comment: You're right... my excuse is that (a) it explains the difference between App Pinning and Lock Task Mode but (as far as I can see) only mentions calling `startLockTask()` in connection with locking; and (b) on app-pinning it says "_the **device user** can temporarily pin specific apps_" which I took to mean the _user_ (and therefore not the _app_) decides if/when an app is pinned. If an _app_ can chose to "pin itself", it's not obvious.